# Caret column position not retained using up/down arrow keys in Eclipse editor

Tags: eclipse, editor, caret

Suddenly (in the last week or two), in the Eclipse editor window, when moving up or down using the arrow keys, the cursor column position is not 'remembered'.  Used to be that, if I moved up or down to a shorter line of text, then continued to another, longer line, the cursor column position would move back to the column it was in, in the original line.  Now the cursor position moves like it does in Notepad, i.e., once it moves to a shorter line, it does not ever move to a column further right using only the up/down arrow keys.

I must have hit some magic key(s) to do this, but, for the life of me, I cannot find it in the help info, nor in any of the menu options that might indicate this choice.  Drives me nuts, 'cause I really dislike this cursor movement.

Eclipse menu info: Version: 2021-09 (4.21.0)   Build id: 20210910-1417

Image showing before and after both upArrow keys.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/viqtB.png
(This image is edited because screen images don't image blinking cursors.  But it illustrates the issue accurately.)

Comment: Maybe you toggled _Block Selection_ (Alt+Shif+A) mode or _Word Wrap_ (Alt+Shif+Y). Please show some text and tell how to move the cursor to reproduce the issue. Please add also a screenshot to your question.

Comment: I'm afraid neither Alt-Shift-A nor Alt-Shift-Y worked for me.  The caret position is illustrated in the newly attached image.

Comment: I see. I can reproduce it in Eclipse 4.21, but not in 4.20 and not in 4.22 M1. So it seems that it has already been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is indeed an **issue of Eclipse 2021-09 (4.21)** that has **already** been **fixed**.

Use [2021‑12 M1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-12/m1) or wait for Eclipse 2021‑12 which will be released on December 8, 2021.

Comment: Wunderbar!  Thanks! 'Fraid I didn't even think to check the bug reports. Doh!